# I have a recursive function that returns incorrect values. Why might this be and how would I fix it?

Tags: python, recursion

I have this function

```
a = 2
b = 6
c = .4

def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return a
    if n == 2:
        return b
    else:
        return c*f(n-1) + (1-c)*f(n-2)
```

It's a simple recursive function with two base cases. f(1) yields 2, f(2) yields 6, which is good, but f(3) yields 3.6000000000000005, when it should be just 3.6. I don't understand where these extra digits are coming from. What might be causing this?

Comment: pls provide a language tag. its probably resulting from your computation that has some insignificant number at the 22 digit behind the . which then is shown in the fashion you posted. use smth like round() to trunc it to what you need.

Comment: I cannot add an answer any longer, but you can try to fix your math in several ways... First you could set `c=4;d=10` and then `return float(c*f(n-1) + (d-c)*f(n-2)) / d`. Another approach is to use `fractions` module.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the magic of floating point math. You can find a nice answer here: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
Spoiler: no, just difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Using [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) in computers makes it necessary to round numbers because there are infinite real numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 for example. Thus the computer would need infinite memory to represent them. Of course it does not do that but rather uses a discrete number of floating point numbers that can be represented exactly. If the result of a computation happens to not be representable with any of these finite floating point numbers, the result is not exact. This is what happens to you here.